# Spotify API Android ADK

Tags: java, android, xml, api, spotify

The SDK does not have a proper way to set up imports in android studio and is not recognized as a JAR. This leads to unusability. Is there a workaround for this to be used in android studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is identified. It is not currently possible in Android Studio on Mac OS! Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use .jar files, you need to add them into /libs folder. After that add the following code into **dependencies** section of **build.gradle** file:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

After sync process, Android Studio will recognize Spotify imports. Best regards.

Comment: Would you be able to show me where the /libs folder is in the project file tree structure is? Or do you mean the "/External/ Libraries" directory?

Comment: I resolved the issues, it is not possible currently in android studio on Mac OS! Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Spotify SDK library we're talking about you may need to add either of the following to the Gradle config:

#### Spotify App Remote

Be sure to check out their [sample project](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/blob/master/app-remote-sample/build.gradle). Not that this is an Aar, not a Jar.

```
implementation files('path/to/remote/lib/spotify-app-remote-release-<version>.aar')
```

#### Spotify Authentication Library

```
implementation "com.spotify.android:auth:<version>"
```

Comment: Sadly this did not work. The problem is not getting the build.gradle to sync. The problem is that after the sync non of the files from the .aar are importable. This means that the .jar file within the .aar file isn't being seen. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: I resolved the issues, it is not possible currently in android studio on Mac OS! Thank you for your help though!